# How to create file with folders for all users in home directory

Tags: linux, bash

So for example we have 4 users in /home directory:

```
user1 user2 user3 user4
```

What I am trying to achieve is that I create directories with files inside for all these users.

```
/home/user1/dir/anotherdir/somefile
/home/user2/dir/anotherdir/somefile
...
```

For one user I can try something like: `mkdir -p /home/user/dir/anotherdir && touch /home/user/dir/anotherdir/somefile`. But I want a dynamic solution when I don't know how many users are and nor their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use brace expansion to explicitly define each user:

```
mkdir -p /home/{user1,user2,user3,anotheruser}/dir/anotherdir &&
  touch /home/{user1,user2,user3,anotheruser}/dir/anotherdir/somefile
```

If you must use POSIX features only, use a loop:

```
for user in user1 user2 user3 anotheruser; do
  mkdir -p "/home/$user/dir/anotherdir" &&
    touch "/home/$user/dir/anotherdir/somefile"
done
```

If you want to loop over all currently existing usernames, modify the loop slightly:

```
for home in /home/*; do
  mkdir -p "$home/dir/anotherdir" &&
    touch "$home/dir/anotherdir/somefile"
done
```

Comment: `mkdir -p /home/*/dir/anotherdir && touch /home/*/dir/anotherdir/somefile` this command creates folder '*'  in /home directory. P.S using Debian

Comment: Oh, yes. Because the subdirectories do not exist yet. I will remove it from my answer. The loop approach should work regardless

Comment: I don't know the names of the users so looping can't work either.

Comment: @Mrmaster updated answer again. It would be really helpful, if such constraints were specified in the question already (all users vs specific users, know user names vs don't know, …) Otherwise answering will just be (slow) guesswork :)

Comment: It says 'But I want a dynamic solution when I don't know how many users are and nor their names.'  Anyways that's the answer I needed. Thanks!